# Run/Use Eclipse Indigo w/ ADT plugin from External Device

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-adt

I have been doing some research on running Eclipse Indigo from an external device (specifically a USB flash drive) and I have found several methods for doing so and have seen that many people have had success. However, I am concerned about the speed and efficiency of this. Even when I open Eclipse up on my desktop (from the hard drive) at home (Windows 7, 64-bit), Eclipse takes a good amount of time (1-3 minutes) to boot up before it is ready to use. Granted I have a large number of projects in my workspace, but my question is, **does running Eclipse Indigo w/ an ADT plugin from a flash drive, create any lag, or speed/efficiency problems, that would not be happening if it was running from a hard drive?**

Comment: I would imagine that once you have it running in memory, there would be little difference. It would just take you some time to get it loaded. Also try save files to host machine not Flash Drive